# Unable to run Unit Test when call function in @PostConstruct

Tags: java, unit-testing, jpa, mockito, ejb

I'm woking on `EJB Project`, using `JPA` to `query data`. Now, I create `unit test` and use `mockito` to `mock data`. There is a function that I call data from `criteria builder`, and it's called from `@PostConstruct`. So if result is empty, then it will throw `NoResultException`. However, I am unable to run unit test to test it. Take a look on source code below:

For class **RefdataUpdateDaoImpl**

```
public class RefdataUpdateDaoImpl{
    public RefdataUpdate getSingleUpdate() {
        CriteriaBuilder cb = getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<RefdataUpdate> query = cb.createQuery(RefdataUpdate.class);
        Root<RefdataUpdate> rootEntry = query.from(RefdataUpdate.class);

        CriteriaQuery<RefdataUpdate> all = query.select(rootEntry);
        TypedQuery<RefdataUpdate> allQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(all);
        return allQuery.getSingleResult();
    }
}
```

In `RefDataCacheBean`

```
@PostConstruct
private void postConstruct() throws Exception{
    cachedUpdateTs = RefdataUpdateDaoImpl.getLastUpdate();
}
```

This is **unit test**

```
@Test(expected = NoResultException.class)
    public void testExistingRefDataUpdate() throws NoResultException{
        update.deleteRefDataUpdate();
        refdataServiceBean.getLastUpdate();
    }
```

So in unit test, it loads data from `dataset xml`. So when I run test, it supposes to throw `NoResultException` and test passes, but test fails and console log no entity data found.

Please help to create unit test in this case, when function's called from `@PostConstruct`.

Trace Logs:

```
javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query
```

Thank you and any comments will be appreciated.

Comment: can you post the sacktrace in the log?

Comment: Hi Simon, post edited, please take a look on trace logs. Thanks. It means in case allQuery has no data, then allQuery.getSingleResult(); throw exception

Comment: Not sure if that's the actual problem, but `throws NoResultException` should not be needed here (since it's a subclass of RuntimeException). Might want to try without that.

Comment: You've posted the code for `getSingleUpdate`, but your `postConstruct` uses `getLastUpdate`. Is that a typo? By the way, you shouldn't use `EntityManager.getSingleResult()` here. It will throw exception if the query result contains more than one result as well. `getSingleResult()` should only be used when the query is *bound* to return a single result (e.g. `SELECT MAX(...)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the NoResultException is nested in a EJBException so your test code should be:

```
@Test(expected = EJBException.class)
public void testExistingRefDataUpdate() throws NoResultException{
    update.deleteRefDataUpdate();
    refdataServiceBean.getLastUpdate();
}
```